Enforce that two columns increase together in Postgresql
CREATE TABLE rides (
  car_id   INTEGER,
  mileage  INT4RANGE,
  date     DATE,
  EXCLUDE USING GIST (car_id WITH =, mileage WITH &&)
);

I have a table rides with a date and an int range mileage. I'm use a btree_gist exclusion constraint to ensure that the mileage ranges don't overlap for a car. However, I also have to enforce that a ride with a higher mileage took place on the same or a later date than a ride with a lower mileage.
In other words, date1 >= date2 if mileage1 > mileage2. I can enforce this with a row level trigger, but that seems to be a bit inefficient (especially since I'm already using an exclusion constraint anyway) and my gut feeling says it should somehow be possible with an exclusion constraint. Does anybody know how?
Example data
# assume same car_id for all rides

"ride_1": {
  "mileage": [0, 50),
  "date": "2024-07-10"
}

# this ride is ok, because mileage is higher and date is the same
"ride_2": {
  "mileage": [50, 100),
  "date": "2024-07-10",
}

# this ride is ok, because mileage is higher and date is later
"ride_3": {
  "mileage": [100, 150),
  "date": "2024-07-11",
}

# this ride should fail, because mileage is higher on an earlier date
"ride_4": {
  "mileage": [150, 200),
  "date": "2024-07-09",
}

Trigger
With a row trigger on insert or update, I could do something like (in pseudocode):
SELECT date FROM rides WHERE mileage < NEW.mileage ORDER BY mileage desc LIMIT 1
IF NEW.date >= date THEN <proceed> ELSE <raise constraint err>



Since mileage is a range I am not sure how you plan to determine date1 >= date2 if mileage1 > mileage2? 2) Sample input data and expected output would go a long way to getting an answer to this. Add as text update to question text. FYI, this mileage WITH <> is saying the mileage values are not equal, not that they don't overlap. That would be the && operator.


Apologies, the operator && was always used, <> was a typo. Since the ranges don't overlap, we can determine if m1 > m2 by simply looking at either the lower or the upper bounds, i.e. m1 > m2 if low(m1) > low(m2).


Your sample data would fail the overlap test as you are using inclusive([]) bounds and this means select '[0, 50]'::int4range && '[50, 100]'::int4range;  t 2) I only see this working using a trigger.


It's just some pseudo json, not meant to denote inclusive bounds. The upper bound is exclusive. I've adapted the notation. The data does not fail the overlap test, and even if it did, that is not the question that I'm asking.


Pseudo or not the data needs to match the explanation. Attention to detail solves a lot of problems. 2) I see the date ordering precluding using a GIST constraint. You will need to use a trigger.

